# Can the variance of a continuous random variable with known distribution be impossible to find?

Tags: self-study, variance, continuous-data

I am solving a problem where the life expectancy of a microorganism can be modeled as having the PDF:

$
f(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      kx^{-3} & x\geq 1 \\
      0 & x \lt 1 \\
\end{array} 
\right.
$

Where $k=2$. I've calculated the average to be 2 hours, but when I try to calculate the variance as:
$$\sigma^2=\int_1^\infty x^2f(x)dx - \mu^2$$

The integral doesn't converge. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's absolutely possible that an expectation exists by a variance does not.

Comment: I had no idea, thanks! The integral turns out to be $log(x)$ evaluated from 1 to $\infty$, so I think it's not possible to find the variance in this case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a special case of the Pareto distribution., which has density of the form $kx^{-(\alpha+1)}$ and for which only moments strictly lower than $\alpha$ are finite.